# Using Plotcandle with condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

how can i use a boolean inside Plotcandle?

```
plotcandle(open_c, open_c, close_c, close_c, title='Candles', color=open_c < close_c ? color.new(#003c7f,50) : color.new(#991722,50), wickcolor=na, bordercolor=open_c < close_c ? color.new(#003c7f,50) : color.new(#991722,50))
```

What im trying to do is using a boolean input and then plot when checkbox is `True`:

```
candle_bool = input.bool(defval=true, title='Candles')
```

As i use to do with the classic `plot()` function for plotting conditionally:

```
plot(candle_bool ? open_c : na [.....])
```

But how can i do a similar job with `plotcandle()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title sasys `plotshape()` but your question has `plotcandle()`.

You can use the `display` argument in both cases.

```
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, "Bar", display=candle_bool ? display.all : display.none)
```